# xamarin ios screenshot and email

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

How to take screenshot and send to a email with a button ?
I have did the coding for taking screenshot, but it will saved to photo album.

```
    partial void btnScreenshot (NSObject sender)
    {
        UIImage image;
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (View.Frame.Size);
        //new iOS 7 method to snapshot
        View.DrawViewHierarchy (View.Frame, true);
        image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
        //...code to save to photo album omitted for brevity
        image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((img, err) => {
            if(err != null)
                Console.WriteLine("error saving image: {0}", err);
            else
                Console.WriteLine ("image saved to photo album");
            UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Screenshot", "Image saved successfully", alertDelegate, "OK", null);
            alert.Show();
                alert.Show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to send it as an email?

Comment: Would appreciate if you could provide feedback on my answer, and hopefully accept it. Thanks

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the advice below. Sorry had been busy recently with other functions first. I have just tried your code, and yes it does work! thanks alot! But does it really send a mail out on emulator ? how do I accept it ? @Scott

Comment: @zhihao No problem. That's good it works. The simulator won't send the email, it will only pretend to. You will have to deploy to a device to see it work entirely. To accept the answer, click the tick outline below the score on my answer. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) for instructions on how to accept. Thanks

Comment: @Scott oh found. ticked ! alright thanks. A developer account is required to deploy it to a device right ?

Comment: @zhihao :) Yes that's right. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Scott oh. I don't have one. =( thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this [Xamarin tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/email/send_an_email/) for instructions on composing the email.

Then to add the screenshot, you need to use the `AddAttachmentData` method.

```cs
// Take the screenshot
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(View.Frame.Size);
View.DrawViewHierarchy(View.Frame, true);
UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

// Don't save it to the album (unless you need to)

// Create an email
var _mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
_mailController.SetToRecipients(new []{"john@doe.com"});
_mailController.SetSubject("Send Screenshot");
_mailController.SetMessageBody("This is a screenshot of the app!", false);

// Add the screenshot as an attachment
_mailController.AddAttachmentData(image.AsPNG(),"image/png","Screenshot.png");

// Handle the action to take when the user completes sending the email
_mailController.Finished += ( object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) => {
    System.Console.WriteLine (args.Result.ToString ());
    args.Controller.DismissViewController (true, null);
};

// Show the email view
PresentViewController (_mailController, true, null);
```

Comment: Hi @Scott , I was hoping you could help me mate. I am using the same code as above. Everything's fine except that I am trying to take a snapshot of a chart which is wider than the view's frame (the user can scroll). My snapshot is truncated, and I can't seem to figure out how to include the whole part of the chart in the snapshot. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DuncanMcIntyre Assuming your chart is in a UIScrollView in which case you should set the context size to the `ContentSize` i.e. `UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(YourChartScrollView.ContentSize);`, that should work.

Comment: I'm actually using this chart component https://components.xamarin.com/view/barchart and can't seem to figure out if it's using a uiscrollview. I tried using the chart's frame size but still getting the same truncated results.

I even tried UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (new SizeF(800f,800f)); but still no luck.